# Rxjs Can this be altered to return a boolean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I have a service call that gets data for an id from an API, returning a Observable array of objects.  I am mapping the data to return the object ids, which are strings, then searching for a specific id, to see if the user is a member of the group.

Right now, it returns an array single string id if it is found, and undefined if it is not.

```
getGroupIdsForUserId(userId: string):Observable <string>{
    const uri = `${this.baseGraphUri}/users/${userId}/memberOf`;
    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
        return obj.id;
      }).find(id => id === this.tfsUsersGroupId)),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
    );
  }
```

I would like to be able to modify this so that it would return a boolean (true) if the id is found, and false if it is not.

Is this possible?  I'm still struggling with this reactive programming syntax.

Comment: You could use another map operator for that

Comment: The best you will get is an observable for a boolean, but not a plain boolean.

Comment: Just change `find` to `some`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding pipeline, you could add another `map` operator after your first `map`, because the `Observable` pipeline will take the data returned and pass through those operators one by one:

```
.pipe(
      map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
        return obj.id;}).find(id => id === this.tfsUsersGroupId)),
      map(x => x.length > 0 ? true : false),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); }));
```

Or like @Bergi comment, you could use `some` :

```
.pipe(
      map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
        return obj.id;})
     .some(id => id === this.tfsUsersGroupId)),
```

Comment: I don't think checking `x.length` works on the result of the `find`

Comment: The length check does not work.. It's the first one I tried.

Comment: @Bergi and Ethan, I've used some of each.  Thanks for the clarification in your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.includes()` for your success path and `catchError` can take an Observable to return in the event of an error...

```
getGroupIdsForUserId(userId: string):Observable<boolean>{
    const uri = `${this.baseGraphUri}/users/${userId}/memberOf`;
    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
        return obj.id;
      }).includes(this.tfsUsersGroupId)),
    catchError(Observable.of(false))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `!!data['value'].map(...).find(...)` that will turn the result into boolean.

Or maybe more readable approach would be using another `map`:

```
.pipe(
  map(data => data['value']
    .map(obj => {
      return obj.id;
    })
    .find(id => id === this.tfsUsersGroupId)
  ),
  map(Boolean),
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be enough...

```js
getGroupIdsForUserId(userId: string):Observable <string>{
    const uri = `${this.baseGraphUri}/users/${userId}/memberOf`;
    const id = this.tfsUsersGroupId;

    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
    .pipe(
      pluck('value'),
      mergeMap(list => from(list).pipe(
        find(obj => obj.id === id),
      )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not get `undefined` then return true/false in the both array map and then observable. this is not exact code but logic should be libe

```
getGroupIdsForUserId(userId: string):Observable <string>{
    const uri = `${this.baseGraphUri}/users/${userId}/memberOf`;
    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
        return obj.id || false;
      }).find(id => id === this.tfsUsersGroupId)),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
    );
  }
```

The logic is even if the id is not there, return a false so that it will be included

Hope it helps